# "Send an email V2" is not sending emails to other organizational office 365 users, it is only sending emails to Yahoo, Gmail & Outlook

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, power-automate, flow

I have this "Send an email V2" action to send emails to different domains accounts, such as other office 365 tenants, outlook, yahoo & gmail, with the option to Send As (which is currently set as the same account as the service account):

[image]

Now only users that are not within Office 365 will get the emails, for example there is this email:

[image]

Where the To field contains 2 emails; Yahoo email & office 365 organization email >> but only the Yahoo email will get this email, while the Office 365 organizational email did not get any thing. Also if using the service account outlook, I directly send an email to the Office 365 organizational account the email will get delivered, so seems the issue is within the "Send Email V2"? did anyone face such an issue before?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe the email went to the junk folder or the user have set a rule to move the email to another folder. Check those firstly.